# Delphi VirtualTreeView - autofocusing node on node hover

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, virtualtreeview

I'm dragging a node from one app to another. It's working fine only if I previously select node. It's because I collect data using `GetNodeData(FocusedNode)` method.

I'd like somehow auto-focus the node on node hover. Is it possible?

I'm using VirtualTreeView v. 4.8.7

Comment: Got toSimpleDrawSelection set to False and toFullRowSelect set to False

Comment: The title talks about *selecting*, but the body talks about *focusing*. Those are independent states, so which do you really want? Can you please be more specific about what fails?

Comment: @ Rob Kennedy: To start drag I have to select (focus) node first, so I could use FocusedNode property. @TLama both are set to False

Comment: @Rob, one thing is IMHO sure; you cannot drag if you don't have some node focused (thus some node selected). And therefore there's a check `IsAnyHit` before the tree starts to `BeginDrag`.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what's failing. How does dragging start? (manual, or automatic?) When dragging starts, are you saying there is no focused node? I don't see how that can be, since `HandleMouseDown` calls `DoFocusChange` just before calling `BeginDrag`. Where are you calling `GetNodeData(FocusedNode)`?

Comment: I want to drag without focusing node first. It seems the node is selected OnMouseUp - when u drag its only MouseDown - if you havent selected the node first, u can't drag it. Seriously its not that hard to imagine

Comment: Perhaps a node *is* selected on mouse up, but who cares about selection? A node is *focused* on mouse down. You can see that happen in `HandleMouseDown`, can't you? Again I ask, *how does dragging start?* Does dragging start as soon as the mouse button is pressed, or do you have to move the mouse a little bit first? Do you call `BeginDrag`, or does the tree call it for you?

Comment: I have an impression that draging is start a moment after mouse is pressed. The I get an exception because data := drzewo.GetNodeData(drzewo.FocusedNode); was nil

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. Drag is being started (in short) when you press and hold the mouse button when you have some node(s) selected, that's the moment when the `BeginDrag` is called. Sorry, I really have no idea what you are expecting or what you want to achieve because if you want to drag you have to press the button (except that you would have some device reading your mind and deciding that you want to drag).

Comment: Well, My friend doing same project in .NET maneged to focus node using mouse pointer position but he has some special method of treelist avalible. i was just trying to acomplish something similiar. i guess delphi is not that powerful

Comment: It's not about Delphi, but about the TreeView itself and it is very powerful. I seriously have no clue what you want to do. So you want to focus node when you hover it ? If so, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to focus and select node when you hover it, try the `OnHotChange` event with the following

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1HotChange(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; OldNode,
  NewNode: PVirtualNode);
begin
  VirtualStringTree1.FocusedNode := NewNode;
  VirtualStringTree1.Selected[NewNode] := True;
end;
```

Comment: omg, omg, thats TOTALLY what I've been looking for. It also makes navigating over the tree easier thanks to autofocusing on hover. Thank you mate, I owe you!

Comment: You're welcome. I've modified the question, because it was not about dragging, but about node selection on hover.